# Does duplicate Dependency affect APK size?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

This [site](http://www.methodscount.com/) helps you in finding the **methods count** of a **gradle** library.

It shows you the number of methods of a library and also the number of methods of all dependencies used in that library. like:

[image]

As the dependencies used by a library increase DEX size like shown in above screenshot.

> If we are using a **dependency** in our project, which is **also used** by
>   another library. Will it increase the DEX size twice?
>
> If yes, can we overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we are using a dependency in our project, which is also used by another library. Will it increase the DEX size twice?

Gradle manages the dependencies for you.
It doesn't download the same library twice and doesn't add the dependency twice.

Comment: Dependency that we add for androidTest will increase the size of apk?